How to Load an Already Instantiated Hugging Face Model into vLLM for Inference?
I am working on a project where I need to utilize a model that has already been loaded and instantiated on the GPU using Hugging Face's Transformers library. The goal is to pass this loaded model into the vLLM framework for further processing and inference without reloading it from disk or a model hub.
Here's what I have done so far using Hugging Face to load the model:
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel

# Load GPT-2 model already fine-tuned and available in memory
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')
model.to('cuda')  # Assuming the model is moved to GPU

I am looking for a way to pass this model instance directly to vLLM's LLM class or a similar interface within vLLM that can accept an already instantiated model. The vLLM documentation primarily discusses initializing its LLM class with a model identifier, which it then loads internally.
Is there a way to integrate an in-memory model from Hugging Face into vLLM without reloading it? Specifically, I want to leverage vLLM's efficient serving capabilities with a model instance that is already in use and configured in my existing pipeline.
Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

This doesn't work:
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer

# Step 1: Load and Save the Model using Hugging Face
model_name = 'gpt2'
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Save the model and tokenizer
model_save_path = './model/gpt2'
tokenizer.save_pretrained(model_save_path)
model.save_pretrained(model_save_path)

# Step 2: Load the model in vLLM using the saved model path
from vllm import LLM, SamplingParams

# Assuming vLLM can load models from a path
vllm_model = LLM(model=model)

# Define sampling parameters and prompts
sampling_params = SamplingParams(temperature=0.8, top_p=0.95)
prompts = ["Hello, my name is", "The future of AI is"]

# Generate text using the specified model and parameters in vLLM
outputs = vllm_model.generate(prompts, sampling_params)

# Print the generated texts
for output in outputs:
    print(f"Prompt: {output.prompt}, Generated text: {output.outputs[0].text}")

Error:
Exception has occurred: OSError
Incorrect path_or_model_id: 'GPT2LMHeadModel(
  (transformer): GPT2Model(
    (wte): Embedding(50257, 768)
    (wpe): Embedding(1024, 768)
    (drop): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    (h): ModuleList(
      (0-11): 12 x GPT2Block(
        (ln_1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): GPT2Attention(
          (c_attn): Conv1D()
          (c_proj): Conv1D()
          (attn_dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          (resid_dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
        (ln_2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): GPT2MLP(
          (c_fc): Conv1D()
          (c_proj): Conv1D()
          (act): NewGELUActivation()
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
    )
    (ln_f): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  )
  (lm_head): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=50257, bias=False)
)'. Please provide either the path to a local folder or the repo_id of a model on the Hub.
huggingface_hub.errors.HFValidationError: Repo id must use alphanumeric chars or '-', '_', '.', '--' and '..' are forbidden, '-' and '.' cannot start or end the name, max length is 96: 'GPT2LMHeadModel(
  (transformer): GPT2Model(
    (wte): Embedding(50257, 768)
    (wpe): Embedding(1024, 768)
    (drop): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    (h): ModuleList(
      (0-11): 12 x GPT2Block(
        (ln_1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): GPT2Attention(
          (c_attn): Conv1D()
          (c_proj): Conv1D()
          (attn_dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          (resid_dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
        (ln_2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): GPT2MLP(
          (c_fc): Conv1D()
          (c_proj): Conv1D()
          (act): NewGELUActivation()
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
    )
    (ln_f): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  )
  (lm_head): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=50257, bias=False)
)'.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/gold-ai-olympiad/py_src/training/maf_self_improv_train.py", line 35, in <module>
    vllm_model = LLM(model=model)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: Incorrect path_or_model_id: 'GPT2LMHeadModel(
  (transformer): GPT2Model(
    (wte): Embedding(50257, 768)
    (wpe): Embedding(1024, 768)
    (drop): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    (h): ModuleList(
      (0-11): 12 x GPT2Block(
        (ln_1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): GPT2Attention(
          (c_attn): Conv1D()
          (c_proj): Conv1D()
          (attn_dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          (resid_dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
        (ln_2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): GPT2MLP(
          (c_fc): Conv1D()
          (c_proj): Conv1D()
          (act): NewGELUActivation()
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
    )
    (ln_f): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  )
  (lm_head): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=50257, bias=False)
)'. Please provide either the path to a local folder or the repo_id of a model on the Hub.

ref: https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm/issues/4843
